# Scala 2.10 implicit function over TraversableOnce should accept an Array but doesn't

Tags: arrays, scala, implicit-conversion, implicit

I wrote a simple implicit function: a version of mkString() that works identically but throws an error if the separator is found in any of the arguments being joined. I want to make it work over all sequence-like things, so I declared it as follows:

```
object SafeMkString {
  implicit class SafeMkStringHelper[T](values: TraversableOnce[T]) {
    def safeMkString(sep: String) = {
      values.map { v =>
        val asStr = v.toString
        if (asStr.contains(sep))
          throw new IllegalArgumentException("Value %s in %s contains separator %s" format
            (asStr, values, sep))
        else
          asStr
      }.mkString(sep)
    }
  }
}
```

This works fine for most objects, but fails in Scala 2.10 with something of type `Array[String]`. This is because arrays in Scala are simply aliases of Java arrays and don't inherit from `TraversableOnce`. However, there's an implicit conversion from `Array` to `WrappedArray` that *does* inherit from `TraversableOnce`. Is there some rule in Scala that disallows having an implicit conversion from A -> B and then from B -> C? Is there some way I can get this working other than manually creating another implicit class that explicitly applies `safeMkString` from `Array[T]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In answer to your 1st question, this is from [Programming in Scala (1st Edition)](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/implicit-conversions-and-parameters.html), Chapter 21:

> **One-at-a-time Rule: Only one implicit is tried.** The compiler will never rewrite x + y to convert1(convert2(x)) + y. Doing so would cause compile times to increase dramatically on erroneous code, and it would increase the difference between what the programmer writes and what the program actually does. For sanity's sake, the compiler does not insert further implicit conversions when it is already in the middle of trying another implicit. However, it's possible to circumvent this restriction by having implicits take implicit parameters, which will be described later in this chapter.

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by @jwvh answer (especially the last line of the citation), I came up with the following:

```
implicit class CanBeTraversable[A, T](a: A)(implicit ev: A => TraversableOnce[T]){
  def safeMkString(sep: String) = {
    val values = ev(a)
    ... //put here the body of your method
}
```

What it does is give an implicit conversion from any type `A` that has an implicit conversion to `TraversableOnce[T]` for some `T`. This works for `List` since `=:= : List[T] => List[T]` is an implicit conversion (also, since `Function1` is covariant in its second parameter, `Function1[List[T], List[T]] <: Function1[List[T], TraversableOnce[T]]`). It also works for `Array` since it has the implicit conversion to `WrappedArray`.